# Is there an API to get sales report on Google Play?

Tags: android, statistics, google-play

We have an Androïd app on Google Play and I'd like to retrieve the sales report programmatically.
Apple provides the Autoingestion tool which allows a Java app to retrieve them, and there's even a Ruby port :
https://github.com/siuying/itunes-auto-ingestion

Does anybody know if there's something similar for Androïd or at least an API ?
I could not find it.

Many thanks in advance,

Geoffroy

Comment: Hi, where did you find your Merchant Key? I have no Integration page in my google checkout. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Checkout (which is used by Play for billing) has an API, but you need a merchant key to use it, and it is not available in all countries.

https://developers.google.com/checkout/samplecode

As someone pointed out below, Google Checkout has been discontinued. The new Google Wallet site does not offer a real API, but you can download your reports, which are stored on Google Drive, using the Google Drive API or command line tools. Reports are in CSV format, so they are easy to parse.

Additionally, the Google Play Developer console now shows sales data. Checkout the Andlytics app, it can fetch and display sales numbers (available in the alpha version). It is also open source.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject

Edit 2014/02/18

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Checkout)

> Google Checkout was discontinued on November 20, 2013. The company offered a new solution for certain payments called [Google Wallet](https://developers.google.com/wallet/)

Comment: Thank you so much ! The API is documented there : https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_History_API

Comment: all of that is down

Answer (score 4):

I only have seen Apps that show a webview of the Developer Console. I noticed the URL to the statistic is always the same, year + month, so you could try and read this in. Sadly it only shows sales and not downloads.
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/salesreport/download?report_date=2012_05&report_type=sales_report&dev_acc=%%YOUR_ACC_NUMBER%%

But there seems to be some kind of api when you look at the ajax-requests in the developer console:
https://play.google.com/apps/publish/statistics?dev_acc=%%YOUR_ACC_NUMBER%%
POST: method -> "getCombinedStats"

Comment: For statistics you can use Andlytics. It's also open source if you are interested how it works. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject

Comment: The Alpha version now supports fetching sales data as well.