# How do I download google play install statistics to my database?

Tags: c#

I want to find a way to automate the pull of total installs for each app my company has in Google Play. I want to bring this into our own interal database so we can marry it up with Google Analytics and in-app information we already have.

Can anyone provide the SDK or API I need to download and maybe some helpful hints to automtae this feed on a on-going basis.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you have found or tested sofar.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this and saw among others this question on my search.

The answer to this question states that you would need to scrape the answer.
[Google Play Developer Statistics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971748/google-play-developer-statistics-api)

This states that you can manually download a csv file. 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628&topic=16285&ctx=topic

You could try to use selenium to automatically download the csv file and then read that in.

The answer on this page can also perhaps help you. 
[Is there an API to get sales report on Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141764/is-there-an-api-to-get-sales-report-on-google-play)