# Google Play Developer Statistics API

Tags: android, api, console, statistics, google-play

Is there any API where someone can get Statistics of their Apps from Google Play?
The Android App Andlytics does something like this I think (They have alot of updates though because of changes inside the console...) but is this also possible to develop with an API in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no API currently for the developer statistics. Apps like Andlyitics use screen scraping (stated in the app I believe) and that is why they have to be updated when ever the console changes.

Comment: This was 2 years ago.. I'm wondering if there's any way that we can do that other than screen scraping this time.. Please help..