# Is it Possible to get the Google Play Statistics data About my Apps Using Any Google Play SDK

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

i want to get the Statistics details About my app in Google Play . for Custom Reporting it in my Website . is there any possible way to do it.

sangeeth

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971748/google-play-developer-statistics-api

Answer (score 0):

I dont which details you want, but [Google Analytics SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Google has a great tutorials on how to set up and use Google Analytics for Android here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/

Comment: it is fine for google analytics SDK but i am asking about getting the google analytics data using the statistics Data .

Answer (score 0):

**Currently there is no official google API for doing this.** Analytics is used for in app analysis. The author wants to get the data with is also displayed in the developer console of google, like how many downloads got my app, etc.